# SharePoint out-of-the-box Issue Tracking - what are a good set of choices for the menu 'Issue Status'

Tags: sharepoint, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

The standard SharePoint out-of-the box Issue Tracking list that comes with many site templates, or when one chooses to Create a New List comes with a choice field called 'Issue Status' and the following choices:

- Active
- Resolved
- Closed

Categorically, my non- to semi-technical team members and contributors don't understand the difference between resolved and closed.

What would be a set of choices for this list?  I am in a business intelligence shop where often a issue gets reported, we make some fix we think resolves it, but need a QA person to verify.  Some of the time, the issue needs to be fixed in development, tested, then deployed and the deployment tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, for your case,  I would start with:

- Unassigned *(aka NEW)*
- Active - Development
- Active - Testing
- Active - Deployed
- Resolved
- Closed without fix

Answer (score 0):

You could put a group next to each status to clarify things.

- Active
- Resolved by Developer
- QA Signoff